# how to create an alias function in php

Tags: php, function, class, oop, object

Hi I feel like i need some alias functions in a class for real function to show that there are some functions in the class in the beginning of the class.
What I want to do is below.

```
class foo {

    public function foo();
    public function boo();
    //alias functions to show there are foo and boo functions somewhere below.

    public function foo(){//real function
        //some code here
    }
    public function boo(){//real function
        //some code here
    }
}
```

I saw these kind of class before but I cannot find it anymore.

Please help.

Comment: Why? Is this so you know what the function is called? So you remember that it is there? If so, that's what we have comments for...

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie the reason I want to do this is for my next developer to understand the class easily. Like seeing table of contents in a book.

Comment: Then write a comment explaining the use of the class? However, if the class is that complicated, you might think about redoing the whole thing. But, do not declare functions - what good will that do, except maybe tell someone that they're there? You will still need to explain why they're there - if no explanation, a new dec will just think it's an empty function, maybe not implemented yet. Use comments. Explain what the class does, and what the functions do.

`#function foo() lets you foo some bars with foo
#function boo() lets you boo some foos`

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie alright then I will comment as many as possible for new developer. Thank you for commenting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you saw was an [Interface](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php). Their purpose is to create sort of a map of a class so you know that any class that implements it will have at least the required methods.

```
interface myInterface(){
    // "alias functions"
    public function foo();
    public function boo();
}

class foo implements myInterface{
    // "real functions"
    public function foo(){}
    public function boo(){}
}
```

---

[phpDoc](https://www.phpdoc.org/) might be closer to what you're looking for. This is a sort of comment syntax that most IDE's use to read and autocomplete methods in your classes. In Netbeans for example, your IDE will offer a method description with parameters and whatever other info you provide. Here's an example from [EasyImage](https://github.com/Pamblam/EasyImage) source code:

```
/**
 * Add perspective to an image
 * @param float $gradient - gradient of perspective
 * @param type $rightdown - angle
 * @return \EasyImage
 */
public function perspective($gradient = 0.85, $rightdown="top"){ ... }
```

Using this function in Netbeans, showing function description and parameters:

[image: Autocomplete in Netbeans]

Comment: While that might be useful in some cases, I still think that the better approach for the  problem the OP explained is to document, comment and actually make sure the code is understandable. :)

Comment: I've edited the question with your feedback in mind, @junkfoodjunkie.

Comment: Many thanks! Interface was the one I was looking for!!!